# filtrar una búsqueda desde android con ws y mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

Buenas estimados, tengo una app que hace un filtro de busqueda pero estoy perdido en una parte, tengo un spinner llenado con nacionalidades (colombia, chile, peru,etc) y al momento de seleccionar una nacionalidad e ir a buscar me trae la persona de dicha nacionalidad, hasta ahi todo bien, pero en el momento de ir a buscarlos todos no se como hacerlo, nose si la intervencion se hace en la consulta select? aparte de nacionalidad, es ciudad y sector que son spinner que contienen caracteres, en los numericos lo tengo resuelto.

estaria muy agradecido de su ayuda, adjunto el ws que hace la consulta, desde android me conecto por json y envio los parametros por url.

**Filtro.php**

```
public static function getByDatos($Precios1,$Precios2,$Nacionalidad,$Ciudad,$Sector,$Edad1,$Edad2)
{

    // Consulta de la tabla 
    $consulta = "SELECT Nombre, id_cliente, Foto FROM `Cliente` WHERE Precios > ? and Precios < ? and Nacionalidad= ? and Ciudad = ? and SectorFiltro = ? and Edad > ? and Edad < ? ";
    try {
        // Preparar sentencia
        $comando = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
        // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
        $comando->execute(array($Precios1,$Precios2,$Nacionalidad,$Ciudad,$Sector,$Edad1,$Edad2));

        $row = $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Aquí puedes clasificar el error dependiendo de la excepción
        // para presentarlo en la respuesta Json
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**ObtenerFiltro.php**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
if (isset($_GET['Precio1'])) {
    // Obtener parámetro 
    $parametro1 = $_GET['Precio1'];
       $parametro2 = $_GET['Precio2'];
          $parametro3 = $_GET['Nacionalidad'];
             $parametro4 = $_GET['Ciudad'];
                $parametro5 = $_GET['Sector'];
                   $parametro6 = $_GET['Edad1'];
                      $parametro7 = $_GET['Edad2'];
    // Tratar retorno
    $retorno = FiltroDatos::getByDatos($parametro1,$parametro2,$parametro3,$parametro4,$parametro5,$parametro6,$parametro7);
    if ($retorno) {
        $cliente["estado"] = 1;     
        $cliente["sector"] = $retorno;
        // Enviar objeto json
        print json_encode($cliente);
    } else {
        // Enviar respuesta de error general
        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '2',
                'mensaje' => 'No se obtuvo el registro'
            )
        );
    }
} else {
    // Enviar respuesta de error
    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '3',
            'mensaje' => 'Se necesita un identificador'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que primero hagas pruebas solo con PHP para verificar la salida de un resultado.

Luego, cuando ya funcione, puedes pasar a realizar las consultas desde android